# How to make a connection string for sql server 2005 with a instance that works for all default sql express default instance?

Tags: connection-string, ssms, sql-server-express, setup-deployment

I have built my database in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and in deployment on my C#.NET application I have added SQL Server Express Edition with the application ..

I was using connection string

```
server=My-PC\\SA;database=My_database;uid=sa;pwd=sql;"
```

Now on deployment it gives error of instance. So how to make a connection string defaultly that works for both SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and SQL Server Express Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this should work,

```
Server = .\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI
```